# EAT hooking reading bad memory

Tags: c++

Trying to do simple EAT hooking

```
DWORD module_address = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("opengl32.dll");

const auto exportDirectory = reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY>(module_address + header->DataDirectory[0].VirtualAddress);

const auto exportFunctions = reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(module_address + exportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);

const auto exportNames = reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(module_address + exportDirectory->AddressOfNames);

const auto exportOrdinals = reinterpret_cast<std::uint16_t*>(module_address + exportDirectory->AddressOfNameOrdinals);  // not sure how this is used yet

 //   auto foundExport = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(module_base + pe_name_table_rva[pe_ordinal_rva[i]]);

for (auto i = 0; i < exportDirectory->NumberOfNames; i++)   // number of names was used previously
{
    auto foundExport = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(module_address + exportNames[exportOrdinals[i]] );

    if (!std::strcmp(foundExport, "wglSwapBuffers"))
        std::cout << "found module " << std::endl;
}
```

it crashes at (if (!std::strcmp(foundExport, "wglSwapBuffers")))

if I look at watch list it says error reading characters of string and unable to read memory
any particular reasons to why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `foundExport` in your case will point to a random memory address. In particular, it will not point to a valid string. To create `foundExport` you add `DWORD module_address` and `exportNames[exportOrdinals[i]` which is a `uint32`. The result is a number which you then cast to a pointer. `strcmp()´ will then attempt to access this random memory address and most likely crash. The` +` operation you are performing is not a concatenation between strings.

If you intend to create a string here then you should probably use a string or a stringstream to create the desired string, for example

```
std::stringstream s;
s << module_address << exportNames[exportOrdinals[i]];
auto foundExport = s.str();
if ( !strcmp(foundExport.c_str(), "wglSwapBuffers") ) ...
```

Also, I strongly recommend to get rid of all those `reinterpret_cast` in your code. They do incorrect things (as I just explained) and hide problems.